# JavaScript: Parse through odd string to get necessary information (RegEx)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to parse through an oddly formatted string which stores some data necessary for an audio player which I'm building.  An example would be:

```
"a:14:{s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"channels";i:2;s:11:"sample_rate";i:44100;s:7:"bitrate";i:192000;s:11:"channelmode";s:12:"joint stereo";s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:15:"encoder_options";s:6:"CBR192";s:17:"compression_ratio";d:0.1360544217687074952660708504481590352952480316162109375;s:10:"fileformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"filesize";i:7249920;s:9:"mime_type";s:10:"audio/mpeg";s:6:"length";i:302;s:16:"length_formatted";s:4:"5:02";}"
```

It's super ugly.  For each song that I interface with it would include the type of information provided above.  Essentially all I want is the value of "length_formatted" which is "5:02".  I'm assuming I need to use regular expressions to accomplish this, but since don't have any experience with it I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: That's php serialization format. Try https://github.com/bd808/php-unserialize-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```js
string = `"a:14:{s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"channels";i:2;s:11:"sample_rate";i:44100;s:7:"bitrate";i:192000;s:11:"channelmode";s:12:"joint stereo";s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:15:"encoder_options";s:6:"CBR192";s:17:"compression_ratio";d:0.1360544217687074952660708504481590352952480316162109375;s:10:"fileformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"filesize";i:7249920;s:9:"mime_type";s:10:"audio/mpeg";s:6:"length";i:302;s:16:"length_formatted";s:4:"5:02";}"`

document.body.innerHTML = string.match(/length_formatted.*?(\d+:\d+)/)[1]
```

Explaining the regex:

```
/length_formatted.*?(\d+:\d+)/

length_formatted          // match the literal text
.*?                       // till the next ocurrence of
(                         // group in [1]
    \d+                       // at least one digit
    :                         // literal ':'
    \d+                       // at least one digit
)                         // end of captouring group
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var s = '"a:14:{s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"channels";i:2;s:11:"sample_rate";i:44100;s:7:"bitrate";i:192000;s:11:"channelmode";s:12:"joint stereo";s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:15:"encoder_options";s:6:"CBR192";s:17:"compression_ratio";d:0.1360544217687074952660708504481590352952480316162109375;s:10:"fileformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"filesize";i:7249920;s:9:"mime_type";s:10:"audio/mpeg";s:6:"length";i:302;s:16:"length_formatted";s:4:"5:02";}"';

var x = s.split('length_formatted";s:')[1].split('"')[1];

alert(x);
```

Find `'length_formatted";s:'` this string and split it now take the last part and split it by `"` and from the result take the middle part!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var lengthFormatted = string.match(/length_formatted"[^"]*"([^"]*)"/).pop(); // => 5:02
```

This assumes that this:

```
"length_formatted";s:4:"5:02"
```

could also be something like this:

```
"length_formatted";all_kinds_of_random_stuff_h3r3;;;;"5:02"
```

Answer (score 1):

This works. This assumes that s:14 will always be the length. I split the junk on a `;` then see if i had a match to `s:4` and recorded the index. then extracted the text.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    //var cow =  'Check out this image <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" style="border:2px solid #ccc;" /></a> and one with a width <a href="http://link.com"><img src="http://image.com" width="700" align="left" /></a>';
    var yourString = 'a:14:{s:10:"dataformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"channels";i:2;s:11:"sample_rate";i:44100;s:7:"bitrate";i:192000;s:11:"channelmode";s:12:"joint stereo";s:12:"bitrate_mode";s:3:"cbr";s:8:"lossless";b:0;s:15:"encoder_options";s:6:"CBR192";s:17:"compression_ratio";d:0.1360544217687074952660708504481590352952480316162109375;s:10:"fileformat";s:3:"mp3";s:8:"filesize";i:7249920;s:9:"mime_type";s:10:"audio/mpeg";s:6:"length";i:302;s:16:"length_formatted";s:4:"5:02";}"';

    var eachPart = yourString.split(";");

    var re = /s:4/i;
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < eachPart.length; i++) {
        console.log(eachPart[i]);
        var found = eachPart[i].match(re);
        if(found)
            count = i;
    }

    re = /".*?"/;

    var yourLength = extractText(eachPart[count]);
    console.log(yourLength);

});


function extractText( str ){
    var ret = "";

    if ( /"/.test( str ) ){
        ret = str.match( /"(.*?)"/ )[1];
    } else {
        ret = str;
    }

    return ret;
}
```